# How to access route params from a component other then the Router component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React-router 1.0/2.0  one can access routing params as `this.props.params` from a Route component - but there seems no supported way to access params from a component deeply contained in the above Route component.

The data sort of could be accessed through `context.location` but this one throws a warning, stating this is deprecated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting [in the latest version of React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#changes-to-thiscontext), all the context data has been deprecated in favor of `this.context.router`:

> Only an object named `router` is added to context. Accessing `this.context.history`, `this.context.location`, and `this.context.route` are all deprecated. This new object contains the methods available from `history` (such as `push`, `replace`) along with `setRouteLeaveHook`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't include the `location` data, so you'll need to pass it yourself into child (non-route handler) components.

Comment: yeah, thanks - this I know. but context.router does not provide params info

Comment: @PeterAronZentai You are correct... it's possible you're expected to provide `this.props.location` to child components manually, either by passing the prop down or providing your own context.

Comment: Your router link is 404.

Answer (score 0):

Per the 2.0.0 upgrade guide, you should pass `params` or `location` down to child components yourself as needed. See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#accessing-location.