# How to get params from route in REACTJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to get params in my react class

I got file `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { App, addPost, Child } from './components/App';
import { Switch , Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render((
   <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/dodajpost" component={addPost} />
        <Route exact path="/:id" component={App}  /> // this one
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

and now in my class i want to get the param ":id" and send it to server, but i don't know how to get it

```
export default class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,

     };
}
componentDidMount () {
    const { handle } = this.props.match.params
    console.log(handle) // undefined
  }
```

How can I get in `componentDidMount` the params from route?

I tried many things and none working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access route params from a component other then the Router component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699238/how-to-access-route-params-from-a-component-other-then-the-router-component)

Comment: Hi Jechanka, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `Route` has param name as `id`,

```
<Route exact path="/:id" component={App}  />
```

Instead of this,

```
const { handle } = this.props.match.params
```

you should do this,

```
const { id } = this.props.match.params

console.log(id)
```

**Note:** You have 2 `Route's` for App component. So when you are already in App component and try to navigate to `path="/:id"` you will not get `id` value, for that you may need `componentDidUpdate` method.

```
componentDidUpdate () {
  const { id } = this.props.match.params
  console.log(id)
}
```

Or you may have a typo here, `<Route exact path="/:id" component={App}  />`, instead of `App` as component you might have `Child` (Post) component `<Route exact path="/:id" component={Child}  />`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8gxtpx)